# Is it possible to connect Google's "Cloud Machine learning engine with Firebase and Flutter"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, flutter

Ok, let's say I want to use a cross Platform native wrapper like React native or Flutter. Easy stuff here. Of course you can connect them with Firebase for RTDB and more.

What I want to know is if it is possible to use Google Cloud Machine learning engine " **it has an API if you are interested**", with the combination of Firebase and Flutter through firebase's functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> through firebase's functions.

That answers your question by itself. It's firebase functions, aka server side, that will handle stuff.

Since it's server side, and as long as Flutter has a firebase client (and there's one) ;  there's no reason for it to be incompatible with Flutter.

So.. Yeah, possible.